# When I run the following macro I get "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error."

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a novice at this. I'm sure it's syntax related. appreciate any help! The strange thing is that I have this same code working in another module in the same workbook. I copied it to this macro and simply changed the cell references.

Debug highlights the line of code begining with... "Range("O2:O" & EndRow)."

Excel Macro code:

```
Sub insertsubmissionformulas()
  '
  ' insertsubmissionformulas Macro
  '
  Sheets("Client").Select
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client")
    EndRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("O2:O" & EndRow).Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(N2),"",INDEX(Historical!$C:$C,MATCH(N2,Historical!L:L,0)))"
  End With
  '
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need four quotes to show double quotes in your formula for blank, not two.
`"=IF(ISBLANK(N2),"""",INDEX(Historical!$C:$C,MATCH(N2,Historical!L:L,0)))"`

Comment: Great! appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks @RayG. It would be most appreciated if you would mark mark this answer as successfully answered. Glad to help.